# How to use kmongo library for slice operator

Tags: arrays, mongodb, jvm, mongodb-query, kotlin

I don't understand how to use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator in [KMongo](http://litote.org/kmongo) library

Let's say I have some collection and would like to limit of array of the document:

```
collection.find("{}, { some_document_array: { ${MongoOperator.slice}: -1 } }").forEach {
           println(it)
    }
```

this code doesn't work and it will return full array of the document

if I try like this:

```
collection.find("{ some_document_array: { ${MongoOperator.slice}: -1 } }").forEach {
               println(it)
        }
```

It will throw error *unknown operator: $slice*

Any other ways to make slice operator work with [KMongo](http://litote.org/kmongo) library?

Comment: Have not really played with it, but AFAIK the driver bases on the Java Driver for which "projections" are handled with a different method rather than a second argument to `find()`. So rather it's `.find().projection( ... )`. Not sure if the JSON extension things are allowed in projections or if you need to use the more traditional driver methods or BSON document instance there. But it's definitely going to be a chained method from `FindIterable` and not an extra argument.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you so much
 .find().projection("{ array: {\$slice: -1 } }") really works for me!

Comment: That's good. Been meaning to have a play around with it myself, so at least I now know tthe JSON extensions work there as well. Actually nothing in the Unit tests doing projections at all, so the project could do with some contribution.

Comment: @NeilLunn I agree need at least more examples how to use this library.